# Writing binary data from a Nodejs buffer to a blob on Meteor client

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, blob, binary-data

I'm trying to create a CSV file that will be saved with UTF-16LE encoding on the server and then pass the result to the client. This is what I do, in Coffeescript:

```
Meteor.methods {
    iconv: (data, from="UTF-8", to="UTF-16LE") ->
        Iconv = Meteor.require('iconv').Iconv
        iconv = new Iconv(from, to)
        res = iconv.convert(data) 
        res
}
```

Now if I write the file from the server with the line

```
fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/test.csv', res)
```

the file is correctly generated. However, I would like to avoid creating a file on the server and save it directly on the client (using the [filesaver library](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)). The sample client code looks like this:

```
exportToCsv = (data="tête", filename) ->
    callback = (err, res) ->
        blob = new Blob([res], {type:'text/csv;charset=UTF-16LE'})
        saveAs(blob, filename)
    Meteor.call('iconv', data, callback)
```

As you can see, the data I'm testing with is a simple string with a special character (the 'ê'). My problem is that I cannot pass the nodejs buffer to the client. It is automatically serialised into:

```
Object {0: 116, 1: 0, 2: 234, 3: 0, 4: 116, 5: 0, 6: 101, 7: 0}
```

instead of the buffer output that I get on the server:

```
<Buffer 74 00 ea 00 74 00 65 00>
```

The problem is not so much the conversion from hexadecimal to decimal, I know I can convert back to hexadecimal using something `Number(116).toString(16)`. But how do I write this data as binary in the blob?

Answer (score 6):

OK so in the end it turned out that I was almost there. The only thing I needed to do for the data to be saved correctly in the Blob was to get the data as an array of numbers from the server (through the `toJSON()` method) and then to create a `Uint8Array` on the client before saving it to a file blob through the blob.

So on the server:

```
Meteor.methods {
    iconv: (data, from="UTF-8", to="UTF-16LE") ->
        Iconv = Meteor.require('iconv').Iconv
        iconv = new Iconv(from, to)
        res = iconv.convert(data) 
        res
}
```

And on the client:

```
exportToCsv = (data="tête", filename) ->
    callback = (err, res) ->
        byteArray = new Uint8Array(res)
        blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type:'text/csv'})
        saveAs(blob, filename)
    Meteor.call('iconv', data, callback)
```

Comment: You've saved my day, I will love you till the end.

Comment: You also saved my long day ! I'll loved you too !